# tomcat 8/9 not asking for login details

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I had tomcat 7 installed and when I clicked on manager app it would ask to log me in and I would log in fine.

However I was having trouble installing an app through this so I thought I would install tomcat 9 I have it all installed and can access the tomcat page on my web browser fine.  But as soon as I click on Manager app it states

"403 Access Denied

You are not authorized to view this page. "

So it does not even ask me to enter any details.  I have made all kinds of changes to the context files to try and allow my ip such as the below

```
allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|109\.203\.100\.223\.\d+" />
```

I have made all kinds of changes to the tomcat users file.  I have changed the server.xml to run on port 8081 instead of 8080 in case that was the issue but so far nothing has worked so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when making the change to the following file:

***/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml***

The change was added the below code to allow all ip addresses strictly for testing purposes:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           allow=".*" />
    </Context>
```